# Parse content from a specific tag in XML file (Java)

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, sax

I have an XML file as per below, and I need to generate a .txt file with the plain text in the  tag, each one in a row, using Java.

I read that I could use SAX in order to access the different labels, but in this case, where there can be random tags inside the  like in the example below, this is not valid.

What is the best approach to do this? Regex perhaps?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
[...]
<source>
  <g id="_0">
    <g id="_1">First valid sentence</g>
  </g>
</source>
<source>Another valid string</source>
```

The output results.txt should be something like this:

```
First valid sentence
Another valid string
```

Comment: Edited. Sorry I haven't read the random tags part. I would consider the whole document as a string and try to extract the 'random' tags identifiers first.

Comment: Well with SAX you just wait for your start tag, turn on a flag, and then collect all the characters you see until you see the closing tag. Just ignore the start and end events for the inner tags.

Comment: @JPMoresmau so in your solution I would still need to use regex in order to discard the <g> tags (example above), if present. Right? Wouldn't it be easier to consider the whole XML as a string and apply regex, as Slow Trout suggests?

Comment: Well no, the SAX events will tell you "I start the source tag", and that's your cue to start collecting text. Then you'll get a SAX event telling you "I'm starting a g tag", that doesn't change anything. Then when you get some some text that you collect, until you see the event "close tag source", you stop collecting the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `joox` library to parse `xml` data. Using its `find()` method you can get all `<source>` elements, and then use `getTextContent()` to extract its text, like:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import static org.joox.JOOX.$;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException {
        $(new File(args[0]))
            .find("source")
            .forEach(elem -> System.out.println(elem.getTextContent().trim()));

    }
}
```

I will assume a well-formed `xml` file, like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <source>
        <g id="_0">
            <g id="_1">First valid sentence</g>
        </g>
    </source>
    <source>Another valid string</source>
</root>
```

And it yields:

```
First valid sentence
Another valid string
```